# check collection length - unobtrusive validation - asp.net mvc 3, 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I've got [custom ValidationAttribute with implemented IClientValidatable](https://github.com/ypapax/MyCollectionCountValidatorClient). It works great using(Html.BeginForm()) but not working using(Ajax.BeginForm()).

Client code:

```
   $(function() {
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('collectionLength');
    });
```

Server code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Require a minimum length, and optionally a maximum length, for any IEnumerable
/// </summary>
sealed public class CollectionMinimumLengthValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    const string errorMessage = "{0} must contain at least {1} item(s).";
    const string errorMessageWithMax = "{0} must contain between {1} and {2} item(s).";
    int minLength;
    int? maxLength;

    public CollectionMinimumLengthValidationAttribute(int min)
    {
        minLength = min;
        maxLength = null;
    }

    public CollectionMinimumLengthValidationAttribute(int min, int max)
    {
        minLength = min;
        maxLength = max;
    }

    //Override default FormatErrorMessage Method  
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        if (maxLength != null)
        {
            return string.Format(errorMessageWithMax, name, minLength, maxLength.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format(errorMessage, name, minLength);
        }
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> list = value as IEnumerable<object>;

        if (list != null && list.Count() >= minLength && (maxLength == null || list.Count() <= maxLength))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

     public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = " CollectionMinimumLengthValidation", ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage("Error") };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("min", minLength);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", maxLength);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

CollectionMinimumLengthValidation.js file:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("CollectionMinimumLengthValidation", function (value, element, param) {
    debugger;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you post your Javascript code where you have define the collectionLength client side validator?

Comment: @nemesv add js. But seemingly it never called.